# Migration from Bugtracker to Atlassian JIRA (Html tags)

Tags: c#, jira

I am trying to migrate some bugtracker data to jira using C# and te soap client interface. So far so good with the implementation but i need to parse some html information to wiki confluence(I guess that is what jira uses). I do understand that wiki does not support break lines but on the following example. how do I parse this text to a proper wiki style. (

```
<h1>This is a text</h1><p> Hello World Luis Mayorga </p><br />
```

). Unless there is a library or external code that i can use on this C# migration tool.

```
content = content.Replace("<br />", "\\");
content = Regex.Replace(content, "<p>(.*?)</p>", "$1");
content = Regex.Replace(content, "<h1>(.*?)</h1>", "h1. $1");
```

**Any Help**

Comment: did you consider [html macros](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Enabling+HTML+macros)? these would allow straightforward wrapping like `{html}<h1>This is a text</h1><p> Hello World Luis Mayorga </p><br />`

Comment: i don't think i can use macros for the migration. I guess i need to enable that macro on JIRA and don't think that is the way to go. Any other clues?

Comment: well per my reading of [this discussion at Atlassian forums](http://forums.atlassian.com/message.jspa?messageID=257232237) you're rather out of luck then

Comment: That is a **good question**. There are more than 3000 issues to be migrated. But i guess not to many are being active right now. I should post that answer shortly.